# how to decode base64 to image in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, buffer

I'm sending an image encoded as base64 through sockets and decoding is not working. The file that must contain the new image is written as base64 instead of a jpg file.

encoding socket:

```
function encode_base64(filename) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, filename), function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      var dataBase64 = data.toString('base64');
      console.log(dataBase64);
      

      client.write(dataBase64);
    }
  });
}

rl.on('line', (data) => {
    encode_base64('../image.jpg')

})
```

decoding socket:

```
function base64_decode(base64str, file) {
  
   var bitmap = new Buffer(base64str, 'base64');
   
   fs.writeFileSync(file, bitmap);
   console.log('****** File created from base64 encoded string ******');
  }


client.on('data', (data) => {


    base64_decode(data,'copy.jpg')

  
});

// the first few characters in the new file 
//k1NRWuGwBGJpmHDTI9VcgOcRgIT0ftMsldCjFJ43whvppjV48NGq3eeOIeeur
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change encode function like below. Also, keep in mind new Buffer() has been deprecated so use Buffer.from() method.

```
function encode_base64(filename) {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, filename), function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
      throw error;
    } else {
      //console.log(data);
      var dataBase64 = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
      console.log(dataBase64);
      client.write(dataBase64);
    }
  });
}
```

And decode as Below :

```
function base64_decode(base64Image, file) {
  fs.writeFileSync(file,base64Image);
   console.log('******** File created from base64 encoded string ********');

}

client.on('data', (data) => {
    base64_decode(data,'copy.jpg')
});
```

Comment: the terminal of the receiving socket gave this error:
TypeError: base64str.split is not a function
    at base64_decode (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Node\sockets\client2.js:17:28)

Comment: is data string?

Comment: on " client.write(dataBase64) " the data is string

Comment: the terminal wrote it "File created from base64 encoded string" but the jpg file is still written as base64 (no image is made)

Comment: Can you give one more try I have changed decode method code a bit

Comment: thank you a lot for helping me but the file is still writing a base64 characters

Comment: can you check data type of 'data' at receiving end?

Comment: the data type is buffer

Comment: is it TCP socket for writing buffer?

Comment: yes, a the encoding socket is client sending to server then send it to another client.
i am using this:   var net = require('net');  var client = new net.Socket();

Answer (score 15):

You can decode the base64 image using following method .

**EDITED**

> To strip off the header

```
let base64String = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA'; // Not a real image
// Remove header
let base64Image = base64String.split(';base64,').pop();
```

> To write to a file

```
import fs from 'fs';
fs.writeFile('image.png', base64Image, {encoding: 'base64'}, function(err) {
    console.log('File created');
});
```

**Note :-** Don’t forget the {encoding: 'base64'} here and you will be good to go.

Comment: it gave me an error:
 DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues
so i changed it to  Buffer.from(data, "base64")
but the file is still written in base64 not as jpg

Comment: try to give you another solution .

Comment: I have updated my code , you can check it out . @AliHmede

Comment: What is image.png? And how do you access result of this?

Comment: Image.png is a file name you wanted to be, and result is seen/access in file named image.png @Grogu

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Buffer.from` to decode the Base64, and write it to a file using `fs.writeFileSync`

```js
const { writeFileSync } = require("fs")

const base64 = "iVBORw0KGgoA..."
const image = Buffer.from(base64, "base64")

writeFileSync("image.png", image)
```

If you have the Base64 string inside a file, you need to decode it into string first, like:

```js
const { writeFileSync, readFileSync } = require("fs")

const base64 = readFileSync(path, "ascii")
const image = Buffer.from(base64, "base64")

writeFileSync("image.png", image)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the decoding function `base64_decode` gets the data as a buffer.
Thus, the encoding argument in `new Buffer(base64str, 'base64')` is ignored. 
(Compare the docs of [`Buffer.from(buffer)`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_buffer) vs [`Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_string_encoding)).

I suggest to convert to a string first

```js
function base64_decode(base64str, file) {

   var bitmap = new Buffer(base64str.toString(), 'base64');

   fs.writeFileSync(file, bitmap);
   console.log('******** File created from base64 encoded string ********');
  }
```

Comment: strange characters appeard in the file "not base64 even"
���

Comment: Right. Actually it's another issue, because `k1NRWuGwBGJpmHDTI9VcgOcRgIT0ftMsldCjFJ43whvppjV48NGq3eeOIeeur` is not a valid base64 string. Try to `console.log` the first 10 characters written to the client with the first 10 chars received by the `base64_decode` function.