# Upload svg and then retrieving firebase storage issue using cloud functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, svg, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload images/svgs to Firebase storage but it doesn't work when i upload svg files and the fetch them using download URL.

I am converting my files to base64 and then passing it to cloud functions from where i am converting them back to file using buffer (i don't know about this part much i just followed some tutorial for this).

I am converting base64 to file using following code

```
const fileName = randomString();
const mimeType = image.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)
  ? image.match(/data:([a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[a-zA-Z0-9-.+]+).*,.*/)[1]
  : null;
const base64EncodedImageString = image.replace(
  /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/,
  ""
);
const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(base64EncodedImageString, "base64");
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
bufferStream.end(imageBuffer);
```

Then i am uploading it to firebase storage using following code

```
 const file = bucket.file("causesImages/" + fileName);
  const response = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    bufferStream
      .pipe(
        file.createWriteStream({
          metadata: {
            contentType: mimeType,
          },
          public: true,
        })
      )
      .on("error", function (err) {
        console.log("error from image upload", err.message);
        reject({ success: false, message: err.message });
      })
      .on("finish", async function () {
        const signedUrls = await file.getSignedUrl({
          action: "read",
          expires: "03-09-2491",
        });
        console.log("signedUrls", signedUrls);
        resolve({ success: true, url: signedUrls[0] });
      });
  });
```

The downloadUrl works fine for png, jpeg, jpg file types but for svg it doesn't work most probably because when i converted image back to file from base64.

Here is an url of one svg file: https://storage.googleapis.com/infaque-playground.appspot.com/causesImages/kaXXidBwhuRjFy5d1aWFB8ibd?GoogleAccessId=infaque-playground%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=16447017600&Signature=NfJZkCWHu8d8nVE9dtDflkwrb8KfW8DTbai2lUN0GOxkCvaJ50X%2FE5b8nby6vudN4AAbvTPwtPhW%2F7fDI08TsYgSUH4Lye%2B6pal8dMV4FLabj256s9ureAaXs0fRJph5gfTmvVeXygwCoExefkFxytbTBrBthJQlpdvHCOazVV8op%2BQzAgPS5SdJFP80SuTuBHHQT%2FL8wYMeW33tdRyWFeZuyunhY7cDyMGlcVj%2F7oBTwl%2B45y1yBwbByDFqjVRCi5nfIGdCaVQ71xGmLEXS0lMs5j0sQJGNK0wG2fGFPzC5jwtSBV747I3PsxllXI4ADUUB%2FyUsrbXVsAFc01%2F7PQ%3D%3D

What am i missing here.

Comment: Are you getting any error while uploading the svg file? If so, could you share the error screenshot?

Comment: No, actually i am not getting the error but when the image is uploaded to firebase storage it creates a link. When i open the link in new tab it says "The page contains the following error: endcoding error". The link of error is in question.

Comment: You may refer to the [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886005/how-to-decode-base64-to-image-in-nodejs) and the [documentation](https://dev.to/dnature/convert-a-base64-data-into-an-image-in-node-js-3f88) which mentions about encoding data into base64 sting and back to an image in Node.js. Let me know if it helps!